# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' with Hello World program in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm working on a simple swift app, using the guide found at this website(http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-part-4-adding-interactions/). I'm at the forth step as shown above, and my code compiles but I get an exception when I actually run the code. This is the top of the exception:

> 2014-12-30 16:54:52.514 HelloWorld[3058:151440] Unknown class _TtC10HelloWorld14ViewController in >Interface Builder file.
>   Hello World!
>   2014-12-30 16:54:52.538 HelloWorld[3058:151440] -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: ?>unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcff07375d0
>   2014-12-30 16:54:52.542 HelloWorld[3058:151440] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception >'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: >unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcff07375d0'

I will add the code I have for a SearchResultsViewController and an APIController which contains code to make a call to the google API. I also have a table in the Main.Storyboard which is a datastore and delegate for tableData variable in SearchResultsViewController.

SearchResultsViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class SearchResultsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, APIControllerProtocol {

    @IBOutlet var appsTableView : UITableView?
    var tableData = []
    var api = APIController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        api.searchItunesFor("Angry Birds")
        api.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")

        let rowData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary

        cell.textLabel?.text = rowData["trackName"] as? String

        // Grab the artworkUrl60 key to get an image URL for the app's thumbnail
        let urlString: NSString = rowData["artworkUrl60"] as NSString
        let imgURL: NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString)

        // Download an NSData representation of the image at the URL
        let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: imgData)

        // Get the formatted price string for display in the subtitle
        let formattedPrice: NSString = rowData["formattedPrice"] as NSString

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formattedPrice

        return cell
    }

    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary) {
        var resultsArr: NSArray = results["results"] as NSArray
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableData = resultsArr
            self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
        })
    }

}
```

APIController.swift:
    import Foundation

```
protocol APIControllerProtocol {
    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary)
}

class APIController {

    var delegate: APIControllerProtocol?

    init() {
    }

    func searchItunesFor(searchTerm: String) {

        // The iTunes API wants multiple terms separated by + symbols, so replace spaces with + signs
        let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

        // Now escape anything else that isn't URL-friendly
        if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            let urlPath = "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=software"
            let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                println("Task completed")
                if(error != nil) {
                    // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
                    println(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                var err: NSError?

                var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
                if(err != nil) {
                    // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                    println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as NSArray
                self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)
            })

            task.resume()
        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated, I've spent a couple hours trying to solve this and searching for an answer but to no avail. I think the problem lies some where in the fact that I renamed SearchResultsViewController and that the variable tableData isn't properly linked anymore but I have no evidence that is correct. Thank you again.

Comment: BTW: there is a rename tool in Xcode. Select what you want to rename and CTRL-Click and use the "Rename…" command from the "Refactor" menu. And let it make a snapshot before you actually apply changes so if things go wrong you can go back in a snap.

Comment: @Zero yes I'll go about it this way next time, didn't think it would be a problem but I think it's the root of all this.

Comment: It's probably easy to start from scratch with a new project. Also, if you're keen to know what exactly happened you can compare the two projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unknown class _TtC10HelloWorld14ViewController in >Interface Builder file

There's your answer. The problem is that you changed the name of the ViewController class, to SearchResultsViewController - but you didn't tell the storyboard about that. You need to tell it. Find that scene and tell it the correct view controller class name in the Identity inspector.

[image]

> I think the problem lies some where in the fact that I renamed SearchResultsViewController

Yes, I see now that you already know this. So just fix it.

Comment: how do I go about changing it? I tried re-assigning delegate and datastore in the mainstoryboard, I can't find any other code references to it so I'm not sure what else to change that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you _read_ what I said? I didn't say anything about the delegate and the data source. I said to put the correct view controller class name in the Identity inspector for this view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: @NNNNNNNNNNDelicious Somehow you must select "that thing" in IB so the "Identity Inspector” shows you the class (name). It will show the name before you renamed it, so put the new name there.

Comment: Thanks for both your help I'm very new to this.. I have the identity and type bar on the side, is this the one I'm looking for because I can't find any class names to change here.

Comment: I've drawn you a picture.

Comment: Found it now, much appreciated for your help!

Comment: You made it possible :)